# materialize css multiple select with springboot

Tags: java, jquery, spring-boot, materialize

I am currently working in springboot with materialize css used in the frontend,
while using the materialize css multiple select,running the html file alone works like a charm, but when i integrated my html file with spring boot, it throws me a runtime error ,code is given below.

**Code: ()**

```
 <div class="input-field" multiple>
    <select>
        <option value="english">English</option>
        <option value="tamil">Tamil</option>
    </select>
    <label>Materialize Multiple Select</label>
 </div>
```

**Error code :**

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Attribute name "multiple" associated with an element type "div" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1472) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanAttribute(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1531) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1315) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2784) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.xmlsax.AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.doParse(AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.java:209) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.xmlsax.AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.parseTemplateUsingPool(AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.java:134) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.xmlsax.AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.parseTemplate(AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.java:116) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:278) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1104) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1286) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.35.jar:8.5.35]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.35.jar:8.5.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.35.jar:8.5.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.35.jar:8.5.35]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.35.jar:8.5.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.35.jar:8.5.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.35.jar:8.5.35]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.35.jar:8.5.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.35.jar:8.5.35]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.35.jar:8.5.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.35.jar:8.5.35]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.35.jar:8.5.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.35.jar:8.5.35]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.35.jar:8.5.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.35.jar:8.5.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.35.jar:8.5.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.35.jar:8.5.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.35.jar:8.5.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.35.jar:8.5.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.35.jar:8.5.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.35.jar:8.5.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.35.jar:8.5.35]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.35.jar:8.5.35]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.35.jar:8.5.35]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.35.jar:8.5.35]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.35.jar:8.5.35]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.35.jar:8.5.35]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.35.jar:8.5.35]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_191]
```

**output got in running html file without springboot:**
[image]

Excepting the same with springboot, but ended up in error :/
Any kind of suggestion will be helpful!!

Comment: Your _code_ seems to be HTML, but you seem to parse it as XML. That won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

didn't work for me, but i found a work around :-} added this section of code alone dynamically to the page using jquery so that eclipse can't throw error in html at runtime, anyhow thanks for the response :)

Answer (score 0):

You should add `multiple` attribute to `<select>` tag, not `<div>`.

Please Change your html code to this :

```
<div class="input-field">
    <select multiple>
        <option value="english">English</option>
        <option value="tamil">Tamil</option>
    </select>
    <label>Materialize Multiple Select</label>
 </div>
```